# visual studio 2013 hide build progress window

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On visual studio 2013 community, each time I build, a build progress windows appear and disappear when building is finish.
Is there an option to hide, never show, this window?
thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's different in the community edition... do you mean the `Output` window? If so, at least in the PRO edition, you have `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Show output window when build starts`. Otherwise, I don't think I've never seen that "build progress" window

Comment: @Jcl Oh sorry I found the solution. This window was genered by 'codemaid' extension.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This windows is generated by the 'CodeMaid' extension. To disable it open Codemaid's configuration and under 'Progressing' uncheck 'Show build progress window when a build start'.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I accidentally undocked it and was having zero luck redocking it and didn't need it anyway.  I didn't realize it was CodeMaid.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but thanks so much. This was such an annoying issue. A side effect of this option, is that it would ALWAYS activate the Error List window regardless of there being errors or not.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what extension was creating this build progress window, or how to make it stop.

Comment: Wow! Thank you - I thought I'd caused it, but in fact I had just installed CodeMaid to try it out. That is a world class crazy bit of UI design.

   CodeMaid.Uninstalled = true

Comment: Just ran into this issue in VS2022. CodeMaid is a good little extension but thats an annoying behaviour.