# Why is Visual Studio showing an "Add Progress" popup that runs for ever?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image: visual studio Add Progress]

I'm having trouble with this window: sometimes when I save changes it shows up and freezes the whole Visual Studio, and sometimes takes several minutes; and, if I close Visual Studio, my changes go away? I cannot find any settings to shut this down: do you have some ideas?  (PS I have "tsf" on).

Comment: I found the same problem here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/144003/add-progress-window-freezes.html. The user who posted this complain did not provide a dump file so the error could not be investigated. Maybe you can open a new ticket there and provide a dumpfile (there is a how to provide a dumpfile in the link).

Comment: I also found an post here on stack overflow where the accepted answere says, it has something to do with the codemaid extension. Do you use this extension? Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902600/visual-studio-2013-hide-build-progress-window

Comment: I have shortened your title and made some minor grammatical/format changes to (hopefully) make your question more appealing.